# MATLAB - integers vs decimals assignment strange bug

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

```
newT = [b(i) d(i) a(i) z(i)];
newT, b(i), a(i)
```

Prints

newT =

```
     123         364         123         902
```

ans =

```
 1.234e+02
```

ans =

```
 1.234e+02
```

What is the problem here? Why are the first and third entry in newT rounded to integer values? Why aren't they correctly assigned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike most other programming languages, integer types in Matlab take precedence over floating point types. When you combine them, either through concatenation or arithmetic, the floating point values are implicitly narrowed to integers, instead of the integers being widened to floating point.

```
>> int32(3) + 0.4
ans =
           3
>> [int32(3)  0.4]
ans =
           3           0
```

This is for historical reasons, because (IIRC) Matlab originally didn't have support for integers at all, so all numeric constants in Matlab produce double values, and the promotion rules were created to make it possible to mix integer types with floating-point constants.

To fix this, explicitly convert those int types to doubles before concatenating.

```
newT = [b(i) double(d(i)) a(i) double(z(i))];
```